# Show that jumps of a Poisson process are $\{0,1\}$-valued

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Let $(N_t)_{t\ge0}$ be an $\mathbb N_0$-valued Poisson process on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$. We know that if $N$ is almost surely right-continuous, then $N$ is almost surely nondecreasing. Thus, $$A:=\{\omega\in\Omega:N(\omega)\text{ is not nondecreasing}\}$$ is a $\operatorname P$-null set. Assume $N$ is càdlàg and note that $$B:=\{\omega\in\Omega:N(\omega)\text{ is not càdlàg}\}\supseteq A\tag1.$$ Since $\mathbb N_0$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R$, $$\Delta N_t(\omega)=N_t(\omega)-N_{t-}(\omega)\in\mathbb N_0\;\;\;\text{for all }\omega\in\Omega\setminus B.\tag2$$

> Let $k,T\in\mathbb N$. How can we show that $$\{\exists t\in[0,T]:\Delta N_t\ge2\}\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^{kT}\left\{N_{\frac ik}-N_{\frac{i-1}k}\ge2\right\}\tag3$$ on $\Omega\setminus B$?

In order to prove $(3)$, we may note that if $t\in[0,T]$, then there is an unique $i\in\{1,\ldots,kT\}$ with $$t\in\left[\frac{i-1}k,\frac ik\right)\tag4.$$ Now let $\omega\in\Omega\setminus B$ with $\Delta N_t(\omega)\ge2.$ Since $N(\Omega)$ is nondecreasing, I only obtain $$N_{\frac ik}(\omega)-N_{t-}(\omega)\ge N_t(\omega)-N_{t-}(\omega)=\Delta N_t(\omega)\ge2\tag5,$$ but I don't think that we necessarily need to have $N_{t-}(\omega)\le N_{\frac{i-1}k}(\omega)$.

Comment: A typo at the end - you probably meant $N_{t_-} \ge N_{(i-1)/k}$ because that's what you need to get $N_{i/k} - N_{(i-1)/k} \ge N_{i/k} - N_{t_-} \ge N_t - N_{t_-}$. 

As for the question, I think things are simplified if you work with the partition $\bigcup ((i-1)/k, i/k]$ instead. In this case, because $N$ is non-decreasing, $N_t \le N_{i/k}$ is straightforward, and since $t > (i-1)/k,$ $\lim_{s \nearrow t} N_s \ge N_{(i-1)/k}$. This deals with all $t \in (0,T],$ and $t = 0$ should be handled by definition.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Oops, you're right. And now it's actually easy, as you wrote. Thank you. Regarding $t=0$: This case should be easy, since both sets should empty (since $\Delta N_0=0$ and $N_0=0$) or am I missing something?

Comment: You're welcome. And yeah, that's what I meant with 'by definition' (but in hindsight I could have said it more clearly).